# Should we split the faith-bitachon-emunah tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

There's currently a [faith-bitachon-emunah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faith-bitachon-emunah) that contains questions about both *[emunah](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1398519/jewish/Emunah.htm)*, which I generally understand to mean something like "belief in God," and *[bitachon](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1405289/jewish/Bitachon.htm)*, which I generally understand to mean "trust in God's goodness to us."

Should we split this into two tags and retag the associated 13 questions as necessary?

Note that there currently exists a separate [bitachon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitachon) tag containing one question about *bitachon*, so I guess what I'm calling for is:

- Rename [faith-bitachon-emunah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faith-bitachon-emunah) to `faith-emunah`.
- Remove it from all questions that are not about *emunah*.
- Add the [bitachon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitachon) tag all of the 13 questions that are about *bitachon*, whether they're *also* about *emunah*, or not.
- Provide tag wikis for both tags that are clear enough to distinguish them from each other.

Comment: This proposal would be improved by including proposed tag wikis, to better indicate which questions _you_ are trying to split out of the existing conglomerate tag.

Comment: Also about tags for _emuna_: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1854

Answer (score 2):

I agree and propose the following tag wikis:

> **Bitachon:**
>     Questions about trusting God, Omnibenificence, and Divine Providence in human affairs
>
> **Emunah:**
>     Questions regarding the tenets of Jewish faith, and Jewish "theological doctrine" in as much as that term can be applied.

Comment: Hey, name-bro, thanks for stepping up and doing the writing work!

Comment: On second thought, I think we should combine Emunah and theology

Comment: The technical term in my experience is omnibenevolence.